# Bit wise operations PHP

Tags: php, binary, hex, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have the ASCII string `"FFFFDFFF"`, representing a hexadecimal value. I want to put that value into variable in binary, with every bit as `1` or `0`.  Below is my first attempt, using only one byte equal to `FF` as an example.

```
$bit1 = bindec(00000001);
const BIT2 = bindec(00000010);
$bit3= bindec(00000100);
const BIT4 = 0b00001000;
const BIT5 = 0b00010000;
const BIT6 = 0b00100000;
const BIT7 = 0b01000000;
const BIT8 = 0b10000000;

    $byte4=substr($data[12],0,2);
    $bit4_1= $byte1 & BIT1;
    $bit4_2= $byte1 & BIT2;
    $bit4_3= $byte1 & BIT3;
    $bit4_4= $byte1 & BIT4;
    $bit4_5= $byte1 & BIT5;
    $bit4_6= $byte1 & BIT6;
    $bit4_7= $byte1 & BIT7;
    $bit4_8= $byte1 & BIT8;
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: You use `BIT1` and `3` but don't define them. Do you have `display_errors` on? Also, what's the problem?

Comment: No errors , just the variables  have blank  content, no 0 or 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unpack by bits in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653931/unpack-by-bits-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you want to use `$byte4` variable in you calculations, you're using `$byte1`, which is not initialized thus coerced to `integer` and initialized with `0`. That's why you don't see any bit set in `$bit..` variables.

Second, you need to convert hex string to int, you can use `hexdec`. See example below.

And third, `bindec` accepts string and you're passing integer, which is fine, however I assume you expect `00000010` to be `2`, but it's gonna be `8`. If you start number literal with `0`, you're telling parser that number is octal. So `10` in OCT is `8` in DEC. And `bindec` gets string `"8"`, which is not valid binary representation so it returns `0`.

```
$ff = hexdec(substr("FFFFFDFF",0,2));
echo $ff & 1; echo "\r\n";
echo $ff & 1 << 1; echo "\r\n";
echo $ff & 1 << 2; echo "\r\n";
echo $ff & 1 << 3; echo "\r\n";
echo $ff & 1 << 4; echo "\r\n";
echo $ff & 1 << 5; echo "\r\n";
echo $ff & 1 << 6; echo "\r\n";
echo $ff & 1 << 7; echo "\r\n";
echo $ff & 1 << 8; echo "\r\n";

echo 00000010; echo " <= this is 8, not 2 \r\n";
echo bindec(00000010); echo " <= this is 0, \"8\" (not binary) => 0 \r\n";
```